# How do select specific rows in column that satisfy either argument in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn pandas in python so I created a simple spreadsheet containing several films and imported it to python. How do I select films that are either action or comedy?

So far I have tried

```
df2=df[df['Genre']=='Action' or 'Comedy']
```

and

```
df2=df[(df['Genre']=='Action') or (df['Genre']=='Comedy')]
```

However, this works

```
df2 = df[df['Genre']=='Action']
df2 = df2.append(df[df['Genre']=='Comedy'])
```

but I believe this is an unorthodox way of doing it.

Is there a simpler or cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Try `df[(df['Genre']=='Action') | (df['Genre']=='Comedy')]`

Comment: Thanks that worked! 
I have another question, If I wanted to have it so that it only assigns films that are before the year 2000, do I have to do in another line?

Comment: use `&`. Some thing like `df[(df['Genre']=='Action') | (df['Genre']=='Comedy') & (df['year'] <='2000')]`

Comment: I have put that as an answer now & you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df[(df['Genre']=='Action') | (df['Genre']=='Comedy') & (df['year'] <='2000')]`

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situations, I find the operator `.isin` easier to understand and more compact:

```
df[df['Genre'].isin(['Action','Comedy'])]
```

This way, if you have additional criteria, you don't need to repeat the line that many times. For example:

```
df[df['Genre'].isin(['Action','Comedy','Drama','Romance','Kids'])]
```

Is much better than:

```
df[(df['Genre']=='Action') | (df['Genre']=='Comedy') | (df['Genre']=='Comedy') |
   (df['Genre']=='Romance') | (df['Genre']=='Kids')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, gives you more freedom of adding filter items(genres), instead to chaining more 'or' clauses.

```
required_genres = ['Action', 'Comedy']

df[df['Genre'].isin(required_genres)]
```

Obviously you can chain more arguments with this, to answer your second question :

```
df[(df['Genre'].isin(required_genres)) & (df['year'] <='2000')]
```